# Contact Form 7 Ajax Loading pre Text

Tags: php, wordpress, contact-form-7

I am trying to add text in front of the ajax loading gif in contact form 7. Instead of the loading gif showing when the user hits submit a string of text "Loading..." shows up in front of the gif and the gif shows up. I am using this function to change the location of the loading gif:

```
add_filter('wpcf7_ajax_loader', 'my_wpcf7_ajax_loader');
function my_wpcf7_ajax_loader () {
    return  get_bloginfo('stylesheet_directory') . '/images/load.gif';
}
```

Comment: That filter is only for altering the image `src` attribute; so you won't be able to use it for this purpose.

Comment: Yes, I am just showing what I currently am doing. I am looking for a way to ad text before the loading image.